# how to active R taskcallback after error

Tags: r

i would like to know how to have a callback after an error.

I tried this, but it doesn't work with error :

```
addTaskCallback(
  function(expr, value, ok, visible) {
    print("ok")
    TRUE
  }
)
getTaskCallbackNames()

print(1) #ok 
ls() #ok
dont_exist() # the taskcallback isn't activated
```

**EDIT:**

GOT IT!

```
if (!require(devtools)){install.packages("devtools")}
devtools::install_github("ThinkRstat/fcuk")
library(fcuk)
sl()
iri
view
mea
```

Comment: is it not an option to use try, like this ? `test <- try(dont_exist());if(inherits(test, "try-error")) stop("stopping execution")`

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper of course not ;)

Comment: you might find [this](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/help/04/06/0217.html) and `Advanced Exception Handling` section in [this blog](http://www.win-vector.com/blog/2012/10/error-handling-in-r/) interesting.

Answer (score 2):

R provides some method to add handlers for errors and warnings. You can use something like

```
.Internal(.addCondHands("error", 
                        list(error = function(e) {print("ok")}), 
                        .GlobalEnv, NULL, TRUE))
```

to add a callback function for error. I didn't find much documentation for this, but you can see the source for `withCallingHandlers` and `tryCatch` to see how to use it.

Edit:

And I also find one method to have a callback after an error, but not in a pure R way. It relies on Rstudio's error callback mechanism:

If you use Rstudio,  you will find a global option "error" which Rstudio uses as an error callback function. You can see it by: `getOption("error")` and change it like this:

```
f <- function(){
    print("ok")
}

options(error = f)
```

And if you want to collect the most recent error message, you can use `geterrmessage()`, which is built into R.

Comment: Any idea how to make this instruction persistent ? with the first error, it's ok, but not with the second. Regards

Comment: @VincentGuyader I see.... I will look into it... Sorry that I didn't notice this problem.

Comment: @VincentGuyader I have found some method to have an error callback but the method relies on Rstudio. Have a look to my edit. I think it's more useful to have a pure R way for this, but I haven't found such a way currently and I will keep look into it. It's really useful to have error analysis functionality like this. Please keep working on it!!